# How to semantically validate textX models?

Tags: textx

I have a set of quite complex textX meta-models that I use for parsing files and creating models with. This involves using different custom scope providers.

I would like to verify the produced model to see whether the scope providers are returning with the correct objects. How should I do this? Can this be automatized somehow?

My first idea would be to generate a dot graph from the model and do the verification manually, but this task will probably need to be done multiple times in the future.

Comment: If I understand the problem you are trying to achieve I would suggest you to look through the textX unit tests regarding scoping. You could make a battery of tests operating over your models and your custom scoping providers and verifying your assumptions.

Comment: Yes, that is something that I have started to do now for our unit testing models.

For the final model it will be not a suitable option because it takes a lot of time to develop these tests. Is there a way to auto generate these validation tests somehow? Are there projects that use textX that did something like that?

Comment: I'm not aware of any project that is doing something similar. I'm not sure that auto-generating tests from custom Python scoping providers is even feasible. If you make something in that direction I would definitely want to hear about it!

Comment: I am not sure I understood correctly, what exactly you are trying to validate. Can you add a small example?